# how to get tomcat log file data fromDate to toDate and display in jsp as a file(JAVA)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, logging, filereader

getting the Tomcat log file data by giving specific dates(from and to) and display it as a file in java.

Can anyone please guide me how to do this part asap.

Thanks in Adavance

Comment: iam new to java ,dont know how to approach also but while searching i found some codes to get log file data but i want particaular timestamp like some regular exp need to pass(date) and get only that data

Comment: AWESOME RESEARCH! Yeah, regex is cool, you are on the right track. Are you new to Java or Programming in general? Have you ever heard of the "DTSTTCPW" principle?

Comment: new to java not for programming.sory i dont know DTSTTCPW.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty file with some lines containing log entries from Tomcat.

Start writing some code to read at least one of these lines. Here's a resource that will help you with this task:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Once you read the line, keep studying on how to iterate through all the lines within the file.

The next step is to identify the date, you can assume that the characters will always be on the same position and retrieve the specific digits that you want (e.g., myString.charAt(6) ), convert them to numbers and code some comparison to find the range of the log entries that you want (which can get quite messy) OR you can move on to Regular Expressions and use the Java Time/Date API to process this comparison.

How about finding a match between the "from" parameter that will be used as the input and the line, then you can keep adding all the subsequent lines to a List of log entries until you reach the "to" date, you can keep iterating through the lines and, when you find "from", start adding lines to the list, when you find "to", just break the loop and then you will have the log entries you need.

I'm not going to share any code here because, well.. you probably know the classic saying: "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"

Keep in mind the "DTSTTCPW" principle:
http://www.xprogramming.com/Practices/PracSimplest.html

Answer (score 0):

I will probably regret stepping in here, as I have seen where these sort of posts head.

To answer your question from the comments above: DTSTTCPW is "Do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work".  In other words, figure out what you need to do, then do it in the easiest way possible.

**Step 1**

So, lets take the problem at hand.  You need to read in the log files from the Tomcat logs.  Do you know where those logs are?  If not, figure that out.  If so, good...on to Step 2.

**Step 2**

Can you read in a file in Java?  There are several ways to do it.  I would suggest looking at `File`, `FileInputStream`, and `BufferedReader` as a start.  You can find these in the good-ol-Java API documentation, which I will note is VERY clear and concise.  Once you can read in a file, go to Step 3.

**Step 3**

Using `File`, get a list of all files in the Tomcat log folder.  Again, Java API will help here.  I would suggest looking at the set of `list()` methods, which returns an array of Strings that are the files in the directory (assuming you created the `File` from the directory path string to the Tomcat logs as mentioned prior).  I would suggest adding a `FilenameFilter` to filter just the files you are interested in.

**Step 4**

Start opening and reading files.  Here we can possibly get a little "fancy" by only reading in files that have been modified between your start and end dates, since anything older/younger would probably not contain log entries for the ranges you are looking for.  `BufferedReader` is good for text files, and even has a `readLine()`.  Once you get the file reading in, move to Step 5

**Step 5**

Upon reading a line, parse it to see what date/time stamp is on it.  There are lots of ways to do this.  `split()` works well if your lines are delimited by spaces, or `substring()` if you know the fall on solid indexed bounds.  REGEX matching/parsing can be used as well if you have something more complicated.  Use the KISS principal here...don't make it hard if it doesn't need to be.  **Note:** I am not going to get into a discussion about REGEX here.  There are entire VOLUMES of information on REGEX, how to write it, etc.  Matching a date/time string using REGEX would not be complicated, and I am sure you can Google and find a solution for that.

**Step 6**

When you pull out the date, convert it to a Java `Date` (See `SimpleDateFormat`) and determine if that line is in range for what you are looking for.  If it is, put it somewhere (a `List`, an `Array` of `String`...whatever) and move on to the next line.  Keep doing this until all Lines of all Files you intend to look at are done.  In the end, you should have the lines you are trying to find.  Return those.

**Step 7**

Print them out in your JSP.  Again, not going to go into depth here as there are probably 1,000,000 possible ways you could decide to do this.  I would suggest looking at Spring's `Model`, putting the data there, and printing it on the JSP.  There are JSP tags for looping and such...Google is your friend.

**Bonus Information**

This is the Bonus round, where we discuss what makes a good StackOverflow post and what doesn't.

First, do your own research.  What I mean by that is: If you have a question like "How do I build a rocket" you are not going to get very good answers.  If you try to start your own rocket, and run into issues with the boosters, then you can ask a more specific question like "I am having premature failure in my booster.  I think my O2 mixture is wrong.  For a 2-ton solid booster, what is the proper O2 mixture to get maximum lift".  See?  The second question is MUCH more specific and answerable.  Could you imagine how long an answer would be to "how do I build a rocket"?  I mean, you could probably write several books on the subject, right?  Almost like asking "how do I write this program as a JSP"...

Second, after you have made a more specific and better researched question, MAKE SURE YOU HAVE CODE EXAMPLES!!!!  Some questions might not warrant code, but must do.  If you are asking something, and you can produce some code that people can use to see what you are doing, then provide the code.  We cannot read minds, nor do we want to waste our time writing our own sample trying to reproduce your problem.

Third, CODE SAMPLES SHOULD BE SHORT, CONCISE, AND MOST IMPORTANTLY RELEVANT!!!  If you are asking about A, but provide a sample of B, then cluttering the question with B only prevents us from answering A.

Forth, POSTS SHOULD ONLY CONTAIN ONE QUESTION, NOT MULTI-PART QUESTIONS!!! We have all done this, and probably still do it, but don't ask questions that require more than one answer.  How are you going to reward people if one person answers one half the question while another answers the other half?  You can't check two questions, can you?  People are here for the "free internet points".

Comment: Also, just an added note: Don't tell people to answer your question ASAP.  I mean, seriously, we are not your workers and are not getting paid.  You have no right to ask us to hurry up.